# How can I add a value in a list of dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, addition

How can I add a hobby to Alex's hobbies?

```
players = [
    {'name': 'Ben', 'age': 31, 'country': 'France', 'hobbies': ['coding', 'biking']},
    {'name': 'Quinn', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Ireland', 'hobbies': ['skiing']},
    {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Lebanon', 'hobbies': ['sports']},
    {'name': 'Alex', 'age': 28, 'country': 'Austria', 'hobbies': []}
]
```

I tried use methods, get, update, use key index and nothing work.

Comment: Why are you using a list for data which should be indexable by name in the first place? And why do you keep person data, which always has the same attributes, in dictionaries? You should use a dictionary of Person objects instead of a list of dictionary objects.

Comment: @zvone Agreed in general. Flat data representations do have their advantages depending on the usecase, but without knowing all usecases for how the data is consumed, indexing based on a particular attribute is potentially not optimal (e.g. perhaps there are duplicates on that index). For simple scripts a class representations might also be overkill, but if this is a pure Python setup I do agree that I would favor a dataclass representation of the object over a dict.

Comment: A list is fine in general, but here the task clearly implies a unique name. The dictionaries are here just wrong. They have a strict list of keys and different types of values. Except in very special situations, dictionaries should not be used for that. A beginner in Python will benefit more from learning that than from solving this particular issue ;)

Comment: You should consider devising a Player class. The data structure you have is both cumbersome and prone to error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you write code that tells you what Alex's hobbies are? If you do that, you get a list, right? Do you know how to add a value to a list? If you try adding a value to the list, that you got back from the first step, does that solve the problem? What happens when you try that? It is not useful to tell us "I tried use methods, get, update, use key index and nothing work.", because that does not **show us** what you tried, and does not **explain what happened** when you tried it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for your comment. I´m a beginner in Python and I´m just solving this problem for practice. Next time I will detail better.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the user `'Alex'`, then append an item to the `'hobbies'` list. To make this easier, rather than using a list of users, you could create a dictionary that maps a name to the user value:

```
players_dict = {player['name']: player for player in players}
```

Now that you have an easy way to lookup users, you can simply search for it and access the `'hobbies'` list.

```
players_dict['Alex']['hobbies'].append('hockey')
```

Without the dict lookup, you could still achieve this with a loop that searches the data:

```
for player in players:
    if player['name'] == 'Alex':
        player['hobbies'].append('hockey')
        break
```

In both cases you would still want to determine what to do when the user requested does not exist. E.g. You could choose to raise an error, or silently ignore the request.